# Tailwind & Vue-Router - dropdown menu doesn't close when clicking on menu items

Tags: vue.js, drop-down-menu, vue-router, tailwind-css, routerlink

I'm using the following dropdown menu in tailwind & vue-router https://codepen.io/huphtur/pen/ordMeN. 
I need to use `<router-link to="/">` inside the dropdown menu, but I found out that doing that, once you click on a menu link the dropdown doesn't close as it should do. Using normal `<a>` elements the dropdown closes like it should.

This is the code:

**dropdown element comp**

```
<div v-if="isOpen == false" class="dropdown inline-block relative sm:ml-20">
          <button class="text-gray-700 font-normal py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center">
            <span class="mr-1 cursor-default">Vita</span>
          </button>
          <ul class="w-32 dropdown-menu absolute hidden text-gray-700 pt-1 shadow-lg z-10">
            <li > <router-link to="/biografia"> <a class="rounded-t bg-white hover:bg-gray-200 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap text-sm"> Bio </a> </router-link> </li>
            <li > <router-link to="/tour"> <a class="bg-white hover:bg-gray-200 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap text-sm"> Tour </a> </router-link> </li>
            <li > <router-link to="/foto"> <a class="bg-white hover:bg-gray-200 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap text-sm"> Foto </a> </router-link> </li>
            <li > <router-link to="/video"> <a class="rounded-b bg-white  hover:bg-gray-200 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap text-sm"> Video </a> </router-link> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
}
```

**css style in the comp**

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

How can I implement this functionality using `<router-link to="/">`?

Thanks!

Comment: RouterLink generates an <a> element in its place. No need to nest another link inside. Just apply the tailwind classes to the RouterLink components.

Comment: Alright, that's a good suggestion but it still doesn't work like it should.

Comment: Can you post more of your code, in particular where youve defined your `<router-view></router-view>`? Even more helpful would be a working example on jsfiddle or a similar site.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

`router-link` exposes a slot for you to enable customizations. I have used this in the past to apply styling to an outer `li` element when the `router-link` was active, but you can use the same approach for closing your dropdown as well.

```
  <router-link
    to="/"
    v-slot="{ href, route, navigate, isActive, isExactActive }"
  >
    <a
      :href="href"
      @click="isOpen = false; navigate($event)"
    >
      Homepage
    </a>
  </router-link>
```

[Source](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#v-slot-api-3-1-0)